# Searchbar to filter contents on a list (macOS Big Sur)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to to implement a search on a datamodel via a searchbar.

My data model is the following struct:

```
struct NoteItem: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var text: String
    var date = Date()
    var dateText: String {
        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMM d yyyy, h:mm a"
        return df.string(from: date)
    }
    var tags: [String] = []
    var filename: String = ""
    var changed: Bool = false
}
```

The application iterates on each element on the data model and populates a list, with a `NavigationLink` that has two `Text`: one with the first line of a `TextEditor`, and another with the `datamodel.dateText`. Each item in the list points to another view where the `TextEditor` displays the full `datamodel.text`

The search I'm trying to add would be only on `datamodel.text`. The code is as follow:

```
struct AllNotes: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var data: DataModel
    ...

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(data.notes) { note in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: NoteView(note: note, text: note.text),
                    tag: note.id,
                    selection: $selectedNoteId
                ) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(getTitle(noteText: note.text)).font(.body).fontWeight(.bold)
                        Text(note.dateText).font(.body).fontWeight(.light)
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
            .frame(minWidth: 250, maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                TextField("Search...", text: $searchText)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .frame(minWidth: 200)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

The searchbar is a TextField in the toolbar.

In iOS, in the past, I've done something similar to this:

```
List(ListItems.filter({ searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.name.contains(searchText) })) { item in
    Text(item.name)
}
```

But given that the searchbar is an item in the toolbar, and that I need to filter / repopulate the list with the search from all the text in the data model, not just the list, how would I even begin to to that? How to filter it? Do I need to populate a new array? How can I access the text on the searchbar? is it `$searchText` in the code I posted? Do I perform `data.filter`?

I've ran out of ideas to try.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I have this sort of working, but note really. It messes up how the `NavigationLink` are displayed, it adds random white spaces before the text.

code:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(data.notes.filter { $0.text.contains(searchText) || searchText.isEmpty }) { note in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: NoteView(note: note, text: note.text),
                    tag: note.id,
                    selection: $selectedNoteId
                ) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(getTitle(noteText: note.text)).font(.body).fontWeight(.bold)
                        Text(note.dateText).font(.body).fontWeight(.light)
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
            .frame(minWidth: 250, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: {
                alert
            })            

            Text("Create a new note...")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10018

Comment: Where in that site? And also, this is not macOS 12, it's Big Sur, so `.searchable` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer edited to so people don't complain:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                List(data.notes.filter { searchText.isEmpty ? true : $0.text.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }) { note in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: NoteView(note: note, text: note.text),
                    tag: note.id,
                    selection: $selectedNoteId
                ) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(getTitle(noteText: note.text)).font(.body).fontWeight(.bold)
                        Text(note.dateText).font(.body).fontWeight(.light)
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
            .frame(minWidth: 250, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: {
                alert
            })            

        }
```

Comment: @KevinSeymour what are you talking about. If you read the code in my question then the answer is clear. But because I don't want to hear complains, here it is. the full answer

Comment: I agree.  I think maybe I pushed the wrong button and I've deleted my comment.  Cheers.